# Using Facebook API (posting in timeline)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Does anybody know is it possible to enhance your site with similar feature of Facebook Timeline: it parses the data (like title, photo, content) from the given URL?

What would be the best solution?

Thanks